# $\int_{0}^{\pi }f(x+t)dt=\int_{0}^{\left [ n\pi \right ]}f(x+t)dt=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals, continuity

Determine the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that:  $$\int_{0}^{\pi }f(x+t)dt=\int_{0}^{\lfloor n\pi  \rfloor }f(x+t)dt=0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R},n\in \mathbb{N}$$
All I've found is that $f = 0$ verifies.
Thank you!

Comment: In the integral limit, is $[\pi n]$ just a parenthesis, or does it denote the greatest integer (floor) function, or something else?

Comment: It's the floor function.

Comment: Do you know that the group of periods of a continuous function is closed?

Answer (score 2):

If $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $L > 0$ such that

$$F(x) := \int_0^L f(x+t)\,dt = \int_x^{x+L} f(t)\,dt\tag{$\ast$}$$

is constant, then $L$ is a period of $f$. That is easily seen by differentiating $(\ast)$,

$$0 = F'(x) = f(x+L) - f(x)$$

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Your condition thus implies that $\pi$ and $3$ (choosing $n = 1$) are periods of $f$.

Hence $S = \{ k\cdot 3 + m\cdot \pi : k,m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is contained in the set of periods of $f$. Since for a continuous function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the set

$$P(g) = \bigl\{ a \in \mathbb{R} : (\forall x\in \mathbb{R})\bigl(g(x+a) = g(x)\bigr)\bigr\}$$

of all periods of $g$ is closed, and $S \subset P(f)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $P(f) = \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f$ is constant. With $\int_0^{\pi} f(t)\,dt = 0$ it then follows that $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: How do we know that $P(g)$ is closed?

Comment: Depends on your favourite way to show that a set is closed. The complement is open: If $a \notin P(g)$, then there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$. By continuity of $b \mapsto f(x+b)$ there is $\varepsilon > 0$ with $f(x) \neq f(x+b)$ for all $b$ with $\lvert b-a\rvert < \varepsilon$, so $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon) \cap P(g) = \varnothing$. It is the intersection of a family of closed sets: For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ let $T(x) = \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : f(x+a) = f(x)\} = f^{-1}(f(x)) - x$. Then $P(g) = \bigcap_x T(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1}(f(x)) - x$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Sorry, I too often forget that the $A \pm x$ notation for translates isn't universally known. $$f^{-1}(f(x)) - x = \{ y - x : y \in f^{-1}(f(x))\} = \{ y - x : f(y) = f(x)\}$$ It's the set $\{ a : f(x+a) = f(x)\}$.

Comment: Ok, then it's the preimage of the closed set $f^{-1}(f(x))$ under addition by $x$, which is continuous. Sounds good.

Comment: Also, did you mean to say that $P(g)$ is the set of all periods of $f$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Oops, typo. Should be $g(x+a) = g(x)$ in that set definition. Fixing.